# Printing in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, printing, flash

How would I go about making a print screen run in flash. So when a user has arranged some artwork via a drag and drop flash/app - they click a button to 'Print' and there current design activates a printer?

Is this straight forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar project and managed with something like the following example:

```
//creating a container as main canvas
var artworkContainers:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(artworkContainers);

//example adding content
var anyContentIWantToPrint:Sprite = new Sprite();
anyContentIWantToPrint.graphics.beginFill(0xf67821, 1);
anyContentIWantToPrint.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
anyContentIWantToPrint.graphics.endFill();
artworkContainers.addChild(anyContentIWantToPrint);

var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
button.graphics.beginFill(0xf67821, 1);
button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 120, 60);
button.graphics.endFill();
addChild(button);

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPrintJobHandler, false, 0, true);

function startPrintJobHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
     printJob.start()

     var printJobOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(); 
     printJobOptions.printAsBitmap = true; 
     //When 'artworkContainer' will be your artwork canvas, where the user will drag and drop. Replace for the instance name you are using.     
     printJob.addPage(artworkContainer, null, printJobOptions);

     printJob.send();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't look to be attached to a mouse click listener though? Although, I might have misunderstood as I'm new to AS3...
:-/

Comment: Don't worry at all.
I just edited my answer adding a 'dummy' button and a mouse click listener. I think it's a start and you will be able to understand more.
Hope was possible to help somehow and welcome to the AS3 gang :)

Comment: Hello thanks, running into an issue. "1120 Access of undefined property artworkContainer" 

     printJob.addPage(artworkContainer, null, printJobOptions);

Something not been declared?
Regards,

Comment: Hello, about the 'artworkContainer', replace it for the current Sprite/MovieClip are you using as main canvas. Where you add your objects you want to print. I just added this name, but, you should replace for your current object instance name.

Comment: Hello, Ah ha! I have just sussed something. I haven't wrapped the stage in anything. All my button's etc are organized into layers, is it possible to print literal stage?  - What's on the screen.
Thanks for your advice so far gPeart.

Comment: Just had another idea... is it possible to print a swf? So if i made another loader to load my current project would I be able to place the wrapper in the loader swf? 

Loader swf > contains project > print snippets is embedded in the loader, if that makes sense?

Comment: If you analyse the source code example I have sent, we are printing a Sprite, when call the addPage method. If you load an external SWF and add on your 'Sprite', you just need to add your Sprite container. I'll edit my answers.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Hope was possible to help! Let me know if works!

Comment: Hello, still having issues, I amended a typo and still... no luck!
is it possible to make all this work from a movie clip instead of your sprite?

I've made a movie clip on my stage called "frame" so what ever sits in that movie clip is printed? I'd imagine it to be quite straight forward?

Regards,

P.S do you have a website?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [`PrintJob`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) class.

You use the FlexPrintJob class to print one or more Flex objects, such as a Form or VBox container. For each object that you specify, Flex prints the object and all objects that it contains. The objects can be all or part of the displayed interface, or they can be components that format data specifically for printing. The FlexPrintJob class lets you scale the output to fit the page, and automatically uses multiple pages to print an object that does not fit on a single page.

> You use the FlexPrintJob class to print a dynamically rendered
>   document that you format specifically for printing. This capability is
>   especially useful for rendering and printing such information as
>   receipts, itineraries, and other displays that contain external
>   dynamic content, such as database content and dynamic text.
>
> You often use the FlexPrintJob class within an event listener. For
>   example, you can use a Button control with an event listener that
>   prints some or all of the application.
>
> **Note:** *The FlexPrintJob class causes the operating system to display a
>   Print dialog box. You cannot print without some user action.*

Here is an [**example**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_3.html) from Adobe's Live Docs.

```
private function doPrint():void {
    // Create an instance of the FlexPrintJob class.
    var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

    // Start the print job.
    if (printJob.start() != true) return;

    // Add the object to print. Do not scale it.
    printJob.addObject(myDataGrid, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);

    // Send the job to the printer.
    printJob.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the [PrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) functionality.  You can add and arrange pages, etc.  Examples on the Adobe help page.